# Mapping exponentiation onto addition

Tags: real-analysis

I was inspired by [Does there exist a function which converts exponentiation into addition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4475785/does-there-exist-a-function-which-converts-exponentiation-into-addition) to think about mapping exponentiation onto addition.
The question asks whether there exists $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(a^b) = f(a) + f(b).$$ Given that $f(a) + f(b)$ is symmetric in $a$ and $b$ but $f(a^b)$ is not, we conclude that $f = 0$ is the only solution.

Let's broaden our scope then, to consider $$f(a^b) = g(a) + h(b).$$ Firstly we note that $f(a^1) = g(a) + h(1)$, so without loss of generality restrict to $$f(a^b) = f(a) + h(b), \qquad h(1) = 0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$ for $a>0$. Letting $a=1$ or $b=0$ implies that $h$ need be constant if $f$ is defined for all positive reals, so restrict to $f : (0,1)\cup(1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

So, then we want to have a natural way to write $h$ in terms of $f$, and then try to solve for $f$.

My first approach was to restrict to $h = k f$ for $k\in\mathbb{R}$ giving $f(a^b) = f(a) + k f(b)$. Then we could look for $f$ with $$f(x^x) = (1 + k) f(x),\qquad f(1) = 0. \tag{2}\label{2}$$

A second idea I had was to let $h(b) = f(b^b) - f(b)$, motivated by letting $a = b$ in \eqref{1}, giving $f(a^b) = f(a) + f(b^b) - f(b)$. Then we would try to solve $$f(e^x) = f(e) + f(x^x) - f(x). \tag{3}\label{3}$$

So my question is, is there a natural solution to \eqref{1}, either by solving \eqref{2}, or \eqref{3}, or otherwise?

Also, logarithms are widely used and it seems that if such functions exist then they could potentially also be useful. Are functions which satisfy \eqref{1} considered in the literature?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation#Commutative_hyperoperations

Comment: It's clear to me that $a^b$ isn't symmetric in $a$ and $b$, but not that $f(a^b)$ isn't; and, indeed, the example of $f = 0$ shows that it can be.  I guess more important is that $f(1^b)$ is constant.

Comment: It's not clear to me what is the intended domain of $a$ and $b$, as $a^b$ is not well defined for arbitrary real $a,b$.  But anyway, the natural solution, which works for $a>1$ and $b>0$, is $\log\log a^b=\log\log a+\log b$.

Comment: If we find that there is no non-trivial solution in reals, how about asking for maps $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ where $f(a^b) = g(a)+h(b)$.

Comment: @Anixx thanks for that link, that seems very apropos. Also to the original poster at math.se.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, [such](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1092631) functions [still](https://mathoverflow.net/a/425063) have $h$ constant (take $a = 1$).  Then the restriction is that $f$ is constant on powers (i.e., that $b \mapsto f(a^b)$ is constant for all $a$), and we may take $g = f$ and $h = 0$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\def\abs#1{\lvert#1\rvert}$Though it’s not clearly stated in the question, I take it $f$ is supposed to be defined only for $a>0$, as otherwise $a^b$ has no sensible definition for non-integer $b$.

For $a>0$, $a\ne1$ and $b\ne0$, a simple solution is
$$\log\abs{\log a^b}=\log\abs{\log a}+\log\abs b.$$

The domain restrictions $a\ne1$ and $b\ne0$ are necessary: as noted in LSpice’s answer, there is no nontrivial choice of $f$, $g$, and $h$ that works for $a=1$, as this forces $h$ to be constant. Likewise, no nontrivial choice works for $b=0$, as it forces $g$ to be constant.

Comment: This is a very nice and simple solution. Do you have thoughts on whether it's unique as a solution to my $(3)$? I think the logarithm is the unique solution to $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$, up to a scaling maybe. I edited my question to specify more clearly

Comment: It’s not going to be unique without some kind of continuity requirement.

Comment: Could you explain why that is? Might it be unique if $f$ is continuous?

Comment: If $f$, $g$, or $h$ is required to be continuous, then it’s not hard to show that the only solutions are $h(x)=\alpha\log|x|+\beta$, $g(x)=\alpha\log|\log x|+\gamma$, $f(x)=\alpha\log|\log x|+\beta+\gamma$ for some constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb R$. For discontinuous solutions, see e.g. the discussion in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation (this is a slightly different equation, but the same applies mutatis mutandis for the equation $h(xy)=h(x)+h(y)$).

Comment: Thanks for the link, this was very interesting and counterintuitive to me. What method would you use to show that the solution you gave is unique? My default is to try and rewrite functional equations as ODEs, but it doesn't always work very well

Comment: You showed yourself in the question a reduction to $h(1)=0$, $g=f$ by subtracting a constant. Likewise, by subtracting a constant from $f$, you can arrange $f(e)=0$, thus $f(e^b)=h(b)$. This reduces the equation to $h(b\log a)=h(b)+h(\log a)$, that is, $h(xy)=h(x)+h(y)$. Then $h(e^x)$ satisfies Cauchy’s equation, thus if continuous, there is $\alpha$ such that $h(x)=\alpha\log x$ for $x>0$. Also, $h(-x)=h(x)+h(-1)$, and $h(-1)+h(-1)=h(1)=0$, thus $h(-x)=h(x)$, i.e., $h(x)=\alpha\log|x|$ for $x\ne0$, and $f(x)=g(x)=h(\log x)=\alpha\log|\log x|$. Now, undo the constant-subtracting reductions.

Comment: Thankyou. This is much simpler than trying to look at $a=b$.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is to the original version of the question, where $f$ was assumed to be defined on all of $\mathbb R$, and the equation $f(a^b) = g(a) + h(b)$ was apparently demanded for all $a \in \mathbb R$.

Since $f(1^b) = f(1)$ equals $g(1) + h(b)$ for all $b$, we have that $h$ is constant, so that $f$ is constant on powers, in the sense that $b \mapsto f(a^b)$ is constant for every $a$.  In particular, $f$ is constant on $\mathbb R_{> 0}$.

I am not sure how to make sense of your proposed equation $f(a^b) = g(a) + h(b)$ for, for example, $a = 0$ and $b = -1$, or $a = -1$ and $b = 1/2$.

Comment: I added the restriction $a>0$ to the question. I think if $f$ diverges at $1$ then it's not necessary to have $h$ constant

Comment: @Joe, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1092630), in the usual usage, a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (or $f : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$) does not diverge at $1$; it is defined there.  Of course it is perfectly possible to ask variants of the question where we allow various singularities, but I think you need to specify exactly what you are asking—otherwise any counterexample can be met by softening the question.  @‍EmilJeřábek
 has [given](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1092626) one example with some domain restrictions.

Comment: Yes OK, I'm coming from mathematical physics and I'm just getting used to being more specific about these kinds of things. I added a restriction to remove 1 from the domain of $f$

Comment: Usual usage for 'function' in mathematical physics is probably something like 'defined on the reals minus some subset of points, differentiable or probably $C^\infty$'. I appreciate that I'm posting on a mathematics forum now though